# Convert Maple online examples into raw text entry?

Tags: command-line-interface, maple

Maple's online help pages render all of the inputs (and outputs) as fancy math (MathJax). I guess the assumption is that you're using the visual IDE. However, I only have access to a terminal with ASCII entry (e.g., via SSH).

How can I can convert the online help pages into something that I can enter directly via the command line?

For example, how do I convert the examples from the [EulerLagrange help page](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=VariationalCalculus/EulerLagrange#examples) into command line entry?

I'm looking for a procedural way or ideally a toggle "switch".

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same help from the on-board help system, which is still accessible via the command-line interface. At the command prompt, enter

???VariationalCalculus,EulerLagrange

(Using Cygwin, I need to hit Enter (or Return) twice for this command to be processed. I don't know if that will be true in SSH.)

The three question marks will take you directly to the Examples section of the help page. The command input of the examples will be in 1D plaintext (aka Maple Input), and the output will be in 2D ASCII (equivalent to **interface(prettyprint= 1)**). You should be able to copy-and-paste the command input. (Using Cygwin, I need to use the Copy and Paste functions directly from the mouse rather than the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V.)